# REST API - SwaggerUI - 404 not found

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger-ui

I created two REST services  for User and Exercise JPA entity.

for the REST service FindAllUsers works but the other one Exercose didn't.

1- User REST service:

```
@Transactional
@Path("/api/v1/users")
@Api(value = "User Service")
public interface UserService {
@GET
    @Path("/getUsers")
    @Nonnull
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    List<User> findUsers();
}
```

2- Exercise REST service:

```
@Transactional
@Path("/api/v2/exercises")
@Api(value = "Exercise Service")
public interface ExerciseService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getExercises")
    @Nonnull
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    List<Exercise> findExercises();
}
```

When i call findExercises() from SwaggerUi interface i always got the HTTP status:

> {   "errorCode" : 404,   "errorValue" : "HTTP 404 Not Found" }

I am new with RSET API , i need a help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have used `@Api.value` wrongly. It should point to the path and you should use `@Api.description` to describe the Api. Finally have a look at the following changes.

```
@Transactional
@Path("/api/v1/users")
@Api(value = "/api/v1/users", description = "User Service")
public interface UserService {
@GET
    @Path("/getUsers")
    @Nonnull
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    List<User> findUsers();
}

@Transactional
@Path("/api/v2/exercises")
@Api(value = "/api/v2/exercises", description = "Exercise Service")
public interface ExerciseService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getExercises")
    @Nonnull
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    List<Exercise> findExercises();
}
```

Comment: the same problem with getExercises and for getUsers i got the error <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2> <p>Problem accessing /rest/api/v1/users/getUsers. Reason: <pre> Request failed.</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/> <br/>